# Azure deploy an application

Tags: azure, scripting, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I am writing an Open Source document management application
All .NET

- App Service
  Host Web and Web Service (WCF)
- SQL Database
- BLOB Storage
  Documents and images
- Table Storage
  Document revision history and search history
- Search
  Document text based search
- Machine Learning
  Advanced document analytics

My question is how do I package that up for someone to just run an installation?

Need to configure the Azure services, copy the code, and copy the database.

On SQL is there a way I can just do a restore of an *empty* database.  Database has some values for like states and system fields.

I see this got a down vote and a close and I am not a arguing with you. There is a button to add a CMS like Drupal. There has to be a facility to do something like this.  I am just asking what tool(s) to use.  Is Azure PowerShell the tool for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's one tool that will do the job for you. IMHO, you will have to make use of a number of things to accomplish this.

The way I see it, you have 4 things that you need to take care of:

1. **Infrastructure Setup**: This would include things like creation of web apps (for website and web services), database servers, storage accounts etc. in your user's Azure Subscription. For this I would recommend that you take a look at [`Template Deployment`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-deploy/). The way I envision this would be working is that you start with a template with lots of placeholders (that you user will fill either manually or through an installer wizard that you will need to create) and then using Azure PowerShell/CLI tools or Azure Portal this template will be deployed. This will ensure that all resources are created.
2. **Database**: You may want to look at `Entity Framework` for that. I believe you would need to use `Entity Framework Code First` approach and this will create the database for you.
3. **Storage Tables/Blobs**: The way we're doing this in our application is that on application start we execute some scripts which consumes Storage SDK to create tables/blob containers/queues if they don't exist.
4. **Code Deployment**: Please see this link for various options on deploying your application to Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/.

Long story short, you will need to roll out your own solution to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't use EF so that is not an option

Answer (score 1):

ARM Template and PowerShell are your friends here, they will get you anything you want.

You can create all the infrastructure you need with ARM, and if anything can't be done through ARM, it will be possible with PowerShell.

The deployment of code and database can be done using PowerShell.

This is the most automated way to do it.

Otherwise, if you want to go classic, create a deployment guide that explains how to do create every resource using the Portal, but this is not recommended